# Using semantic-ui with electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, semantic-ui

I have a headache with the configuration of my project environment. Basically I will use electron + react + redux + semantic-ui-react.

What I've already done is the configuration: electron+react. Now I am trying to use semantic-ui-react.

I added dependencies, installed gulp and semantic-ui but it does not work.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "babel": "babel",
    "webpack": "webpack"
 }
 "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.8.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.3.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.78.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
```

When I enter: `npm run start`, electron window shows up but there is no semantic-ui component which I added to app.js (react container which renders).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Button, Checkbox} from 'semantic-ui-react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={()=> {}}>Xxx</Button>
                <Checkbox label='Make my profile visible' />
                <h1> App </h1>
            </div>
        );
    };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Can anyone suggest something?;)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you imported semantic-ui component in the project ?

Comment: @Aaqib yes, just updated content of question, please take a look ;)

Comment: May I ask why you have two different version of React?

Comment: @ChrisR it was a mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally dealed with it.

Install semantic-ui-css and add

```
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

to your index.html

Comment: If you use react + semantic-ui-react, for what would you use jquery? :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add like this in your `index.html`. Then, run `yarn start` again.:

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="../node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css"
    />
```

It helps you to solve all the css import related issue in electron.

Comment: you should rely on importing files, instead of hardcoding paths